# T. W. Hungerford Graduate Text in Mathematics. Algebra. Definition 7.2

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, definition

In the text it states that:

> **Definition 7.2.** Let $\mathfrak{C}$ be a category and $\{A_i | i \in I\}$ a family of objects of $\mathfrak{C}$. A **product** for the family $\{A_i | i \in I\}$ is an object **P** of $\mathfrak{C}$ together with a family of morphisms $\{\pi_i : P \rightarrow A_i | i \in I \} $ such that for any object $B$ and family of morphisms $\{\phi_i : B \rightarrow A_i | i \in I \} $, there is a unique morphism $\phi: B \rightarrow P $ such that $\pi_i \circ \phi = \phi_i$ for all $i \in I$.

I could not get the part that is defining a "product" as an object of the category. The definition of category is very clear at the beginning of this chapter and it states that $\mathfrak{C}$ contains only the objects however here the "products" also included in it. Is this part of the definition true?

Comment: The product is an object in the category along with some morphisms satisfying certain conditions. This is similar to a topological space being a set along with some subsets of that set (the open sets) satisfying certain conditions.

Comment: Emphasizing the morphisms one could say that a product is a family $(\pi_i)_{i\in I}$ of morphisms with a common domain a codomains $A_i$ such that...

Comment: A product is not just an object; as you wrote it's an object together with a bunch of morphisms. Have you seen direct product of sets, groups, modules, etc.? This is just a more abstract definition in terms of universal property of the $\pi_i$'s. Instead of defining the product of two groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ to be $\{(g_1,g_2):g_1\in G_1,g_2\in G_2\}$, you define it to be a group $H$ together with two group homomorphisms $\pi_1:H\rightarrow G_1$ and $\pi_2:H\rightarrow G_2$ that satisfies certain properties, and it turns out this $H$ must be isomorphic to $G_1\times G_2$ defined in the old way

Comment: Verbatim: "A **product** for the family $\{A_i|i\in I\}$ is an object $\mathbf{P}$". There should be no confusion, since by definition the product object must be an object that 'already exists' in $\mathfrak{C}$

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. For clarification let me put the definition of the category (**Definition 7.1**) here: "A **category** is a class $\mathfrak{C}$ of objects (denoted $A,B,C,...$) together with ..." There are two properties one for *arrows* and one for *compositions*. Isn't it so clear that the category consists of objects only but not products?

Comment: You seem to think that "object" and "product" are mutually exclusive concepts. The definition says the opposite: A product $\dots$ is an object $\dots$.

Comment: Think of examples that you may know: in the category of groups and homomorphisms, every family of groups has a direct product, which is also a group; in the category of topological spaces and continuous maps, every family of topological spaces has its product, which is a topological space. This is simply an abstraction: the product of a family of objects is another objects which satisfies certain properties. One thing to keep in mind: this definition does *not* guarantee existence of products: some categories of products (e.g. groups, topological spaces), some do not.

Comment: It seems that there is a misunderstanding about my question. It is obvious that there is a product for a given family of objects as described in the definition. But the weird thing for me is assuming that it is naturally inside the category. If we consider the category of groups, is the product of any family from this category is also inside the category. It is more intuitive for me to consider it as a separate category with the detailed structure as @blargoner explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the confusion here is caused by the use of "together with". Beyond what has already been said in the comments, the following may help.

To keep things simple, suppose $I=\{1,2\}$. Then a product of objects $A_1$ and $A_2$ in $\mathfrak{C}$ is a diagram in $\mathfrak{C}$ of the form

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
A_1 @<{\pi_1}<< P @>{\pi_2}>> A_2\tag{1}\\
\end{CD}$$
such that for any diagram in $\mathfrak{C}$ of the form
$$\begin{CD}
A_1 @<{\phi_1}<< B @>{\phi_2}>> A_2\\
\end{CD}$$
there's an arrow $\phi:B\to P$ unique making this diagram commute in $\mathfrak{C}$:
$$\begin{CD}
A_1 @<{\phi_1}<< B @>{\phi_2}>> A_2\\
@| @VV \phi V @|\tag{2}\\
A_1 @<{\pi_1}<< P @>{\pi_2}>> A_2
\end{CD}$$
The product is not just the object $P$, it's the whole diagram (1), but we often *informally* say "product $P$" and may even think about it as the object $P$ in $\mathfrak{C}$ when the arrows $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are understood to be "together with" it.

The product (1) is actually an object in a different category, namely the category $\mathfrak{P}$ of "pairs of arrows in $\mathfrak{C}$ from an object into $A_1$ and $A_2$". This category consists of the following data:

- **Objects:** diagrams in $\mathfrak{C}$ of the form $A_1\leftarrow X\to A_2$
- **Arrows:** an arrow from the object $A_1\leftarrow X\to A_2$ to the object $A_1\leftarrow Y\to A_2$ is an arrow $X\to Y$ in $\mathfrak{C}$ making this diagram commute in $\mathfrak{C}$:
  $$\begin{CD}
  A_1 @<<< X @>>> A_2\\
  @| @VVV @|\\
  A_1 @<<< Y @>>> A_2
  \end{CD}$$
  Composites and identities in $\mathfrak{P}$ are inherited from $\mathfrak{C}$.

A product (1) in $\mathfrak{C}$ is precisely a terminal object in $\mathfrak{P}$.

What "is" a diagram as an object in $\mathfrak{P}$ "really"? We could think of a diagram like (1) as a triple $(P,\pi_1,\pi_2)$. Note we need to keep track of the domain and codomain diagrams for the arrows in $\mathfrak{P}$, so an arrow like (2) could be thought of as a triple $(\phi,(B,\phi_1,\phi_2),(P,\pi_1,\pi_2))$.

I should probably clarify that none of this tells you that a product actually *exists* for objects in $\mathfrak{C}$, because a terminal object may not exist in $\mathfrak{P}$. For example, any preorder can be viewed as a category in which the objects are the elements of the preorder and there's a (unique) arrow $a\to b$ if and only if $a\le b$. In such a category a product is precisely a greatest lower bound, which need not exist. Other examples can be found in other answers on this site.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation.